# Pusher UI in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, pusher

I try to get my pusher notifications in dropdown in menu, not sure how to do that, here is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'ap1',
        encrypted: true
      });

      var channel = pusher.subscribe('notify');
      channel.bind('notify-event', function(data) {
          alert(data.message);
      });
</script>
```

on alert i get my notification successfully, but what i'm looking for is to get them in html code below which is placed in my navbar:

```
<a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="label label-pill label-danger count"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
</ul>
```

This is what is look like `html code above`:

[image: screen1]

## UPDATE

I changed my `js` code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'ap1',
        encrypted: true
      });

      var channel = pusher.subscribe('notify');
      channel.bind('notify-event', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#notifs').append('<li>'+ value + ' ' + value +'</li>');
            });
      });
<script>
```

and my `html` to:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="notifs">
</ul>
```

Now I have result like:

[image: screen 2]

> PS: I've tried `$('#notifs').append('<li>'+ value['message'] + ' ' +
>   value['name'] +'</li>'); });` but it returned `undefined` so i just
>   used `value` and that's what i get.

Comment: Are you using a JS framework of any sort? Like Vue.js, which comes default with a new Laravel project?

Comment: @ceejayoz no i don't. all i use is that javascript in my question

Comment: OK, then you're going to have to look at how to do DOM manipulation - stuff like `appendChild` - in raw JS, or adopt a framework of some sort.

Comment: I know about append `success:function(data) {
                $('#des').empty();
                $('#des').append('something here');`

Comment: OK, so do that. Append elements to the dropdown menu.

Comment: @ceejayoz this doesn't work.  `channel.bind('notify-event', function(data) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').empty();
        $.each(data.message, function(key, value) {
            $('.dropdown-menu').append('<p>'+ value['message'] +'</p>');
            });
      });`

Comment: Well, you're trying to put `<p>` tags into a `<ul>`. I'd be a little annoyed as a user if you deleted all my previous notifications with `.empty()` every time I got another one, too. Start `console.log()`ing out the data at various points and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: @ceejayoz I updated my question. would you mind take a look at it?

Comment: @mafortis what you are getting in alert value.message

Comment: i get undefined

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I didn't need to foreach the result just needed to use `data` itself.

```
+ data.message + ' ' + data.name +
```